# Laravel Model relations with foreign key constraints

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, constraints, relation

I'm trying to get foreign key constraints to work in Laravel. But I can't seem to save my models anymore.

My database structure is setup as follows (I've removed unnecessary code):

```
Schema::create($this->tableName, function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('password', 64);

    $table->integer('address_id')->unsigned();
});

Schema::create($this->tableName, function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('surname');

    $table->string('street');
    $table->string('number');
    $table->string('town');
    $table->string('country');
});
```

So the `Address` is in a separate table and an `Address` belongs to a `User`. The `User` has an `Address`.

Next I've created the corresponding models:

```
Class User extends Model
{
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Address');
    }
}

Class Address extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Now when I try to create a `User` with an `Address` and save it I get constraint errors. I've tried it both ways (saving the `User` first and saving the `Address` first) but both give an error.

The first idea I had was this:

```
// Create a new user
$user = new User($data);
$address = new Address($addressData);

$address->user()->associate($user);
$user->push(); // Error here
```

But this gives the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`eet`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_address_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `addresses` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `type`, `phone`, `cellphone`, `newsletter_week`, `ip`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (adsadsad, validemail@gmail.comx, passWO23dw00, customer, 123123213, 1234567890, 1, ::1, 2014-10-05 19:56:03, 2014-10-05 19:56:03))
```

So I tried saving the `Address` first, and then the `User` like:

```
$user = new User($data);

$address = new Address($addressData);
$address->save(); // Error here

$address->user()->associate($user);
$user->push();
```

But then the following error is generated:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `addresses` (`name`, `surname`, `street`, `number`, `town`, `country`, `user_id`) values (Foo, Bar, FooStreet, 200, Townsville, nl, ))
```

So what is a good way to do this? I could make the field `address_id` for the `User` nullable, but is that a good practise? I want a `User` to always have an `Address`.

Answer (score 6):

I would start with database design first.

For `users` table I would use:

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->string('username')->unique();
$table->string('password', 64);
```

address_id is not necessary here.

For `addresses` table I would use:

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

$table->string('name');
$table->string('surname');

$table->string('street');
$table->string('number');
$table->string('town');
$table->string('country');
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('users')
      ->onDelete('CASCADE');
```

You should use foreign key in addresses table and add onDelete('CASCADE`) - now if you remove user, address will be removed automatically. You won't have any orphaned addresses.

Now inserting data:

```
$user = new User($data);
$user->save();
$address = new Address($addressData);
$user->address()->save($address);
```

You don't need to put in `$addressData` any `user_id` - it will be filled automatically.

Comment: Yeah, that was a possibility. But I wanted to differentiate between an home address and a (physical) mail address. So I have an `address_id` and `delivery_address_id` in the users table. If I remove address_id from my user I won't be able to differentiate.

Comment: @Matthijn So `address_id` in User table has nothing in common with `Address` model?

Answer (score 0):

At first save the parent `model` and in this case it's `User` so:

```
$user = new User($data);
$user->save();
```

Then try:

```
// $addressData ...
$addressData['user_id'] = $user->id;
$address = new Address($addressData);
$address->save();
```

Or maybe:

```
$user = new User($data);
$user->address = new Address($addressData);
$user->push();
```

Comment: I'd say the `User` is the "defining entity" here. And a `User` has an `Address`. What I think you are saying is: "Remove the `user_id` from `Address` and you're good to go." But then I could make "orphaned" addresses.

Comment: Does your `address` table has `user_id` ?